# How can I talk to other contracts and store their function call returns as variables?

Tags: solidity, tokens

For example, I want to grab the current borrow rate for a token on compound.finance. In this contract [InterestRateModel.sol](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/master/contracts/InterestRateModel.sol), is there a way to call getBorrowRate from my own contract and get the return stored in a variable? I want to use that borrow rate as an input to a function. How can I do something like this?

Do I need to use an oracle or can I directly communicate with a smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract YourContract {
    //InterestRateModel instance
    InterestRateModel interest_rate_model;

    constructor(address _interest_rate_model_contract_address) public {
        interest_rate_model = InterestRateModel(_interest_rate_model_contract_address);
    }

    function getInterestRateModelBorrowRate() public view returns (uint, uint) {
        return interest_rate_model.getBorrowRate(1, 2, 3);
    }
}

interface InterestRateModel {
    function getBorrowRate(uint cash, uint borrows, uint reserves) external view returns (uint, uint);
    function isInterestRateModel() external view returns (bool);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is very common for smart contracts to call each other's functions and do something with returned results.  To do this, you need the following:

1. The calling contract should know API of the callee.
2. The calling contract should know that address of the callee.
3. The calling contract should be called itself by somebody to have a chance to do something (call another contract in our case).
4. The calling contract should know what to do with the result (store in own storage variable in out case)

Here is how all these could be coded:

```solidity
// 1. Know the callee API
interface InterestRateModel {
  function getBorrowRate(uint cash, uint borrows, uint reserves) external view returns (uint, uint);
  function isInterestRateModel() external view returns (bool);
}

contract Caller {
  // 2. Know the callee address
  InterestRateModel private interesetRateModel =
    InterestRateModel (0xBAE04CbF96391086dC643e842b517734E214D698);

  uint public borrowRate = 0;

  // 3. Get called itself
  function fetchAndSaveBorrowRate () public {
    uint status;
    uint rate;

    // Call another contract
    (status, rate) = interesetRateModel.getBorrowRate (1, 2, 3);

    // 5. Do something with returned result
    if (status == 0) borrowRate = rate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Mikhail-Vladimirov thank you for this example, this is what I've been looking for. It was difficult finding a solid example like this, really appreciate it.